# how to create loading spinner react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

i am totally new to react, here's what i have in my successPg:

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const successPage = props => { 

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) {
   
more code ....


      .then(() => console.log("email out for delivery!"));

    props.history.push('/clients')
    
    })
    
  }
});
}

// 
        
     

  })

  return (
    <input type="hidden"></input>
  );
  
}
  export default successPage;
```

where the `return` is, i want to put a spinning logo there for when the page is loading! Cold anyone help me!? It would help a lot as to understanding react more

Comment: Do you have a spinning logo component you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a loader file Loader.js and use this code

```
import React from 'react';

function ShowDetail() {
  return (
    <div className="loader center">
      <i className="fa fa-cog fa-spin" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ShowDetail;
```

Now open your App component and import the loader file

```
import Loader from './Loader';
```

After successfully import, set the state loading true and use it as a conditional loader.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { loading: true };
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) return <Loader />;
    
    return <ShowDetail details={details} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a boolean to show or not show the spin, for this example we can use `loading`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Spin } from 'antd'

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
setLoading(true)
    if(user) {

      .then(() => console.log("email out for delivery!"));

       props.history.push('/clients')
    
    })
    
  }
setLoading(false)
});
return (
<Spin spinning={loading}>
 <input type="hidden"></input>
</Spin>)
```

Answer (score 0):

An example with the **Font Awesome** spinner icon:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const MyComponent = ({}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  
  const startLoad = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    // Bla bla bla ....
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 3000);
  }
     
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={startLoad} disabled={loading}> Load </button>
      {loading && <i className="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" />}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
button {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```